# Deno: Access query params in controller

Tags: typescript, deno, oak

I wrote a couple of apis for a Deno POC.

This is the route code:

```
const router = new Router()
router.get('/posts', getPosts)
      .get('/posts/:id', getPostsById)
```

For the second route, I am able to get path param in controller: getPostsById using the keyword: params. This is the controller code:

```
export const getPostsById = (
  { params, response }: { params:any, response: any }) => {
    console.log(params, '||| params')}
```

How can I get the query param in similar fashion (eg: /posts/2222?userId=3)

I am using oak for routing. I tried various keywords from oak codebase: query, search etc but no success.

I tried getQuery from the Oak documentation as well, but I am completely unable to import it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Oak ou can use `.searchParams`

```
ctx.request.url.searchParams
```

For getting `userId` you would use:

```
const userId = ctx.request.url.searchParams.get('userId')
```

---

`getQuery` from `helpers.ts` is only on `master` currently since it was introduced 12 hours ago.

Instead of using `https://deno.land/x/oak@v4.0.0/mod.ts` you can import `https://deno.land/x/oak/helpers.ts` that will pull from `master`. This is not recommended though, but will do until a new version is released and you can use a tagged import.

```
import { getQuery } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/helpers.ts'

router.get("/book/:id/page/:page", (ctx) => {
  getQuery(ctx, { mergeParams: true });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! @marcos:  this worked. This is my controller code now:

export const getPosts = (
  { request, response }: { request: any, response: any }) => {
    const userId = request.url.searchParams.get('userId');
    console.log(userId, '||| userId');
}